# which ports should be exposed in a docker container for apache ignite?

Tags: docker, ignite, gridgain

I'm using apache ignite for in-memory cache. I want to deploy my app using docker with swarm mode. Which ports should be exposed in a container? I see in [ignite docker module](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/08606bd468e40f19b46559cce616d73898ec7068/modules/docker/1.8.0/Dockerfile) that these ports are exposed 11211 47100 47500 49112. But in my app log I see different ports like 48100 for shared memory communication.

Answer (score 4):

It's enough to exposed listed ports. Shared memory is not supported by docker, so you may simply ignore it.

```
11211 - REST service port;
47100 - communication port;
47500 - discovery port;
49112 - JMX port.
```